# Deserializing child node with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

What should my POJO declaration be if I want to de-serialize the following JSON format:

```
{
"id":2,
"content":"skfdjhsfjhsfjkshdkjfhskdjf",
"created_at":"2012-11-14T00:10:59Z",
"feeds":
 [
   {
     "feed":{"name":"twitter"}
   } 
 ]
}
```

Currently my POJOs look like that:

Broadcast.java - the outtermost object

```
public class Broadcast {

    private String content;
    private String created_at;
    private Feeds feed[];
    private int id;

    public Broadcast() { }

    public int getId() { return id; }

    public String getContent() { return content; }

    public String getCreatedAt() { return created_at; }    
}
```

Feed.java - the inner child of Broadcast which can be an array and each feed has a name attribute:

```
public class Feeds {

    private String name;

    public Feeds() {}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }   
}
```

Comment: don't you need setter methods if you want to deserialise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private Feeds feed[];`

should be

`private Feeds[] feeds;`.

Actually, the placement of `[]` doesn't matter, but it's recommended to be placed alongside the type as it makes it clearer to read. The issue here is with the incorrect variable name.

---

Also, if you take a closer look at:

```
 "feeds":
  [
      {
          "feed":{"name":"twitter"}
      } 
  ]
```

you'll notice that `feeds` is indeed an array, but `"feed":{"name":"twitter"}` represents a variable (`feed`) holding a key-value pair (`{"name":"twitter"}`), thus your `Feeds` class should look like:

```
class Feeds {
    private Map<String, String> feed;

    public Feeds() {}

    public String getName() {
        return feed.get("name");
    }
}
```